# initialize struct in c

Tags: c, variable-assignment

```
 typedef struct Node{
        int x;
        int y;
        struct Node* next;
    }Node;
```

i want create in main "list" in this way:

```
int main(){
        Node list;
 }
```

and not in this way:

```
int main(){
        Node list = {1,2,NULL};
    }
```

i want initialize a struct in declaration of struct
    tryed this way:

```
 typedef struct Node{
        int x;
        int y;
        struct Node* next;
    }Node = {1,2,NULL};
```

**error C2513: 'Node' : no variable declared before '='**

**need help**

Answer (score 3):

You can't give structure members predefined values in C. Use a constructor-like function or a constructor-like macro.

Comment: @user1354271 Anything I can come up with is just uglier wrapping for `Node list = {1,2,NULL};`.

Comment: the main i can't change, it must be in this way:

    int main(){
            Node list;
     }
but i need initialezed Node for user if his declaration of list in this way

Comment: *Something* in `main()` must be changeable, or how you initialize `Node list` is irrelevant, since it's not used.  If you're going to ask a question like this (that has mysterious homework or interview-like restrictions) please let us know clearly up-front what the rules are so we can avoid playing "20 Questions".

Answer (score 1):

The typedef (or struct) "statement" defines a type, not an object.

Types have no value. It only makes sense to speak of values in relation to objects.

Objects do not have a default value (other than `0` when they're implicitly initialized).

So you can't do what you want.

Comment: its not initialized by defaul to "0"

Comment: When objects are implicitly initialized, they are initialized with `0`: is what I meant.

Comment: the main i can't change, it must be in this way:

    int main(){
            Node list;
     }
but i need initialezed Node for user if his declaration of list in this way